# Creating hash of hashes from list of network interface config files in perl

Tags: json, perl, hash

I'm trying to load the list of network interface configuration files on Linux into the hash of hashes and further encode them into JSON. This is the code that I'm using:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use diagnostics;
use JSON;
use Data::Dumper qw(Dumper);


opendir (DIR, "/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/");
my @configs =grep(/^ifcfg-*/, readdir(DIR));
my $output = "metadata/json_no_comment";
my %configuration;

my $key;
my $value;
my %temp_hash;
foreach my $input ( @configs) {
    $input= "/var/tmp/rhel6.8/" . $input;
    open (my $JH, '<', $input) or die "Cannot open the input file $!\n";
    while (<$JH>) {
         s/#.*$//g;
         next if /^\s*#/;
         next if /^$/;
         for my $field (split ) {
             ($key, $value) = split /\s*=\s*/, $field;
             $temp_hash{$key} = $value;
             }
             $configuration{$input} = \%temp_hash;
         }
     close $JH;
}
print "-----------------------\n";
print Dumper \%configuration;
print "-----------------------\n";

my $json = encode_json \%configuration;
open (my $JNH, '>', $output) or die "Cannot open the output file $!\n";
    print $JNH $json;
close $JNH;
```

The data structure, that I'm getting is following:

```
$VAR1 = {
          '/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-lo' => {
                                           'BOOTPROTO' => 'dhcp',
                                           'NAME' => 'loopback',
                                           'TYPE' => 'Ethernet',
                                           'IPV6INIT' => 'yes',
                                           'HWADDR' => '"52:54:00:65:e7:8c"',
                                           'DEVICE' => 'lo',
                                           'NETBOOT' => 'yes',
                                           'NETMASK' => '255.0.0.0',
                                           'BROADCAST' => '127.255.255.255',
                                           'IPADDR' => '127.0.0.1',
                                           'NETWORK' => '127.0.0.0',
                                           'ONBOOT' => 'yes'
                                         },
          '/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0' => $VAR1->{'/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-lo'}
        };
```

The data structure, I'm looking for is the following:

```
$VAR1 = {
          '/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-lo' => {
                                           'BOOTPROTO' => 'dhcp',
                                           'NAME' => 'loopback',
                                           'TYPE' => 'Ethernet',
                                           'IPV6INIT' => 'yes',
                                           'HWADDR' => '"52:54:00:65:e7:8c"',
                                           'DEVICE' => 'lo',
                                           'NETBOOT' => 'yes',
                                           'NETMASK' => '255.0.0.0',
                                           'BROADCAST' => '127.255.255.255',
                                           'IPADDR' => '127.0.0.1',
                                           'NETWORK' => '127.0.0.0',
                                           'ONBOOT' => 'yes'
                                         },
          '/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0' => {
                                           'BOOTPROTO' => 'dhcp',
                                           'NAME' => '"eth0"',
                                           'TYPE' => 'Ethernet',
                                           'IPV6INIT' => 'yes',
                                           'HWADDR' => '"52:54:00:65:e7:8c"',
                                           'NETBOOT' => 'yes',
                                           'ONBOOT' => 'yes'
                                         }
};
```

Any idea what am I doing wrong? Why the first nested hash is created correctly and the second one is not? I suspect, that it has something to do with reading the files line by line, but I have to do it, because I need to filter out the commented lines before JSON conversion.
Thanks for any help.

Edit: I have modified the script as suggested by Borodin and it works. Thanks!

Comment: What about Sys::HostIP,  Net::Interface or other modules from CPAN? Would that work for you?

Comment: Modules you suggest are good, but I wanted more general solution. With some tweaking I can now parse and encode in JSON also other types of config files, with a different syntax. Thanks for the advice anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `$configuration{$input}` always refers to the same hash `%temp_hash` because you have declared it at file level. You need to created a new hash for each config file by declaring `%temp_hash` inside the `for` loop

Also note that `next if /^\s*#/` can have no effect because you just deleted any hashes in the line. Your sanitisation should look like

```
s/#.*//;
next unless /\S/;
```